# Python 2.x Running command line commands in a different directory

Tags: python, linux

Lets say the Python script I'm running from stored in `~SomeFolder/sample_project`

If I want to run this command:

```
import subprocess

command_pushd ='pushd /Users/user/Desktop/test'.split()
subprocess.call(command_pushd)

>>> ~/Desktop/test ~/SomeFolder/sample_project
```

I want pushd command to refer only to the `/Users/user/Desktop/test` file path. The subsequent command doesn't work and throws this error:

```
command_zip ='zip -r -e -Ptest test.zip ./sample_file.txt'.split()
subprocess.call(command_zip)

zip warning: name not matched: ./sample_file.txt
zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -r -e -Ptest test.zip . -i ./sample_file.txt)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: does not work how? Where are you running command_zip from?

Comment: If I run these commands manually on the command line, it works. But if I try to script it on a .py file, it doesn't work and gives me  a `zip warning: name not matched: ./sample_file_txt` error. The command_zip is run in `~SomeFolder/sample_project`, the same .py file that `command_pushd` is run from

Comment: Did you try `cwd =/home/whatever/SomeFolder/sample_project`?

Comment: No, but I can't believe I didn't think of that. I thought I would have to mess around with  PATH.